# How to calculate the distribution within a series

Tags: probability

The probability of event $A$ happening is $50.7\%$.  The probability of event $B$ happening is $49.3\%$.  What is the probability that in a series of $100$ trials, there will be at least one point where more event $B$'s will have happened than event $A$'s?

Comment: Are events A and B mutually exclusive?

Comment: Do you mean that you have 100 trials and each trial either gives event A or event B, like a coin flip with a biased coin?

Comment: Yes, events A and B are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Yes, there are 100 trials and each trial either gives event A or event B, like a coin flip with a biased coin.

Comment: Perhaps [Bertrand's ballot theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem) is relevant.